# Making sure only one order (or less) is executing for a single player at a given time

Tags: python, architecture, concurrency

To best describe the question, i'll begin with the following scenario:

Suppose i have a poker game:
The player is allowed to use credit in order to purchase some goods.

If the player executes two purchase orders at the same time (theoretically), two workers may handle this request simultaneously and there could be an integrity error, thus the application must make sure that there is only one (or less) orders executing for a single player at a given time.

Just to make sure that the scenario is clear - there could be hundreds of orders executing simultaneously - but for different players

Following the 12Factor guidelines, i should be able to scale out the workers (which actually process the purchase orders).

How can i make sure that only one order (or less) is executing for a single player at a given time with an elegant solution?

Thanks in advance,
Erik.

Comment: It depends. One perfectly acceptable way is to use the *transaction* support provided by a RDBMS to ensure the correct serialization schedule.

Comment: I thought of this too... optimistic concurrency is good.. but the problem is that not all data stores (redis) are transactional and i wouldn't like to make this assumption *yet*

Answer (score 1):

Just a short disclaimer:
I'm no python expert nor a database expert but I fell that my solution below is on the right track. Apply it with your skills and you'll get the result youre looking for.

It's one of a few ways of achieving what you'd like dare I say quite `elegant` :).

Im assuming you have different devices hence how multiple transactions could take place for one particular customer.

Based on that assumption and also the assumption that you have some sort of webservice for the system, I have solved it like this:

Add a table in your database that will record all active customers being handled currently.
Then you add one more check before a transaction with a customer begins on the device to make sure that customer is not on that active transactions table, if so, then reject the new transaction from happening, otherwise continue. This check before hand will ensure that only one transaction can happen for any particular customer at any time no matter how many devices are being used concurrently.

The above is just an example. Its how I am currently handling it, and its working well for me.

It's basically the idea of quickly checking whether that current customer is in the `activecustomers` database, and if so for you to simply reject the customer as that customer is already in a session elsewhere. Once the customer is done with that session, you delete the entry from that table.

Comment: The correct transaction and isolation levels need to be used, but I'm in favor of using the RDBMS as the approach is well proven in terms of correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - please see to comment to @user2864740.
Rejecting the order is unacceptable - i need to queue it for later execution.

Answer (score 0):

Our current solution involves a RabbitMQ exclusive queue (every consume locks the queue until the task is finished) for each player and celery to consume tasks from the queues.

What do you think of this proposed solution?

Erik.